# How can I aggregate on 2 dimensions in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have data in 2 dimensions (let's say, time and region) counting the number of visitors on a website  for a given day and region, as per the following:

| time | region | visitors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Europe | 653 |
| 2021-01-01 | America | 849 |
| 2021-01-01 | Asia | 736 |
| 2021-01-02 | Europe | 645 |
| 2021-01-02 | America | 592 |
| 2021-01-02 | Asia | 376 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-02-01 | Asia | 645 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to create a table showing the average daily worldwide visitors for each month, that is:

| time | visitors |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 25238 |
| 2021-02 | 16413 |

This means, I need to aggregate the data this way:

- first, sum over regions for distinct dates
- then, calculate average on dates

Is was thinking of doing a global average of all lines of data for each month, and then multiply the value by the number of days in the month but since that number is variable I can't do it.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 calculated fields:

1. `Month(time)`
2. `SUM(visitors)/COUNT(DISTINCT(time))`

Comment: Nice, I ended up using this but forgot to update the answer. You could replace `COUNT(DISTINCT())` with the function `COUNT_DISTINCT()` though

Answer (score 0):

In case it might help someone... so far (January 2021) it seems there is no way to do that *in* DataStudio. Calculated fields or data blending do not have a `GROUP BY`-like function.

So, I found 2 alternative solutions:

1. create an additional table in my data with the first aggregation (sum over regions). This gives a table with the number of visitors for each date.
   Then I import it in DataStudio and do the second aggregation in the table.
2. since my data is stored in BigQuery, a custom SQL query can be used to create another data source from the same dataset. This way, a `GROUP BY` statement can be used to sum over regions before the average is calculated.

These solutions have a big drawback that is, I cannot add controls to filter by region (since data from all regions is aggregated before entering datastudio).

Comment: have you looked into custom SQL identifiers? You can use them in the Custom Query. You could add a region one and link it to a input field for example